# org-mode, source code block, result vector

Tags: python, r, emacs, org-mode

In an org-mode to beamer presentation, I want to process data from a spread sheet, using either a `python` or `R` source code block. I know how to do this.

There will be a vector of results, and I need to get individual vector elements on different slides. Is there a way to destructure the results vector, so I don't need to recalculate the spread sheet every time? Maybe make python only store the vector as variable and then use an inline-python-call to extract the value?

Example:

```
#+name: calculation
#+begin_src python :result value
return [1, 2, 3]
#+end_src

*** Slide one
I calculated <how to insert :calculationresult[0]>?
- some 
- content

*** Slide two
I calculated <how to insert :calculationresult[1]>?
- more
- content
```

Answer (score 1):

Just playing around with the documentation and SO, I found the following solution:

- calculate the results inside a code block in session mode
- extract the results in an inline code call which uses the same session

```
#+name: calc
#+begin_src python :session :results output :exports none
  myvec = [1, 2, 3]
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: calc


* Page 1

I got number src_python[:session]{myvec[1]}
```